# Certain Javascript works on single pages, but not when loaded globally via a Drupal theme's javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal-7, global

On the SO-chat, I was advised to ask the following question here:

I would like to load some *Javascript* globally on my complete website, via a Drupal theme's *Javascript*; insead of having to re-insert the *Javascript*-code each article over and over again.

For example, I have managed this with the following code (imagine it wrapped in `<script type="text/javascript">`...`</script>`, when inserted locally):

(which worked fine both locally when inserted per page, and also when loaded in to the Drupal theme's javascript globally as such):

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $
        $(".toggler").click(function () {
            $(this).next().slideToggle("slow");
        }).next().hide();
        $("a[href^=#]").click(function () {
            var id = $(this).attr('href');
            $(id).parents('.toggled').fadeIn("fast");
        });
    });
})(jQuery)
```

However, for 2 other pieces of *Javascript*, I can't get things to work when loading them globally. However, they work great when inserted locally in to each consecutive article, as such (I'll mention just 1 smaller code, for reference):

(imagine it wrapped in `<script type="text/javascript">`...`</script>` again, when inserted locally):

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        function getKey(element) {
            return element.href;
        }

        function sameGroupAs(element) {
            var key = getKey(element);
            return function() {
                return getKey(this) === key;
            }
        }
        $(document).on("mouseenter", "a", function() {
            $("a").filter(sameGroupAs(this)).addClass(
                "active");
        }).on("mouseleave", "a", function() {
            $("a").filter(sameGroupAs(this)).removeClass(
                "active");
        });
    });
})(jQuery)
```

Just for reference: if you would be interested how I added the [*Javascript* to a Drupal's theme](https://www.drupal.org/node/304255).

Comment: **Hint:** Aha: I can only use 1 *Javascript* code at a time for the moment ... I can choose to **EITHER** load the first, **OR** load the second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simply to put every single "script" in a seperate `.js`-file. If they were put into one `.js`-file, they would simply all become dysfunctional.

Anyone knows whether this is a Drupal-specific strategy, or whether this is general to *Javascript* and known to everyone in "the field"?

Comment: Hou should be able to combine both scripts by combining the contents of the document.ready function. You'll need that only once and the behaviour should remain the same. I also don't know what the dollar sign does at lines 3. As far as I know that serves no extra purpose.

Comment: @Neograph734 - Nice catch. Enclosing them in the `$(document).ready(function() {` could certainly be submitted as an answer, as this seems to solve the problem as well. =)

Answer (score 1):

This problem is unrelated to Drupal, and is just a javascript thing. I suppose (but did not test) it occurs because you are defining an anonymous function `(function($) {...})(jQuery)` twice. As in all languages two function names may never be the same. Details should have been visible in the JavaScript console of your browser if you want to know for sure.

Apart from that, it is neater to combine both scripts into one, as they both fire when the document has loaded. If you require more visibility on what part of the script performs a certain function, splitting it over multiple files (as you already discovered) works as well.